# Unable to view the docker selenium script execution on VNC Viwer

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a selenium script as below:

```
public class firstclass {   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    new DesiredCapabilities();
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.99.100:4443/wd/hub");
    RemoteWebDriver rwd = new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap);
    rwd.get("https://www.google.com");
    try {   Thread.sleep(1500); } catch (InterruptedException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
    System.out.println("Title of the page : "+rwd.getTitle());
    rwd.quit();         
    }
 }
```

This works fine when I run from eclipse.
Then I started by Selenium Hub and Chrome containers from docker and here is a result of the docker ps command:
[image]

On my browser , I can see the following.
[image]

I used the VNC viewer from chrome webstore. I tried with different IPs, but still I can't login to the chrome container to view the execution. It keeps saying unable to connect.

Which IP I need to use?

Comment: Docker is exposed in localhost:5555 and localhost:4444

Comment: Why do you think there should be vnc server? It should be running on a certain port in container which has to be mapped to some external port

Comment: @PDHide , Thank you but i tried both. it did not work.

Comment: @AlexeyR.: basically i want to see the execution on chrome. yes, i agree but which port. i use VNC viwer to see the execution.

Comment: I mean why do you think it is even possible? Are you following some tutorial?

Comment: Assuming you're using [the SeleniumHQ images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium), I think you need to expose port 5900 out to the host?  There's some details in the readme.MD

Comment: @AlexeyR.. Yes. i saw in both Youtube and some tutorials. how can they get it and i cant. and also i need to set it up for our project .